# Recommendations for a "Getting started with Greasemonkey" tutorial

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, greasemonkey

I'm interested in writing some Chrome compatible [Greasemonkey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey) scripts, but I'm finding that there are few updated tutorials on how to really get started properly with writing userscripts. [Dive Into Greasemonkey](http://web.archive.org/web/20110726001221/http://diveintogreasemonkey.org/) by [Mark Pilgrim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_Pilgrim_%28software_developer%29) is five years old now and hasn't been updated. Searches for tutorials are rife with garbage hits, affiliate blog links and general nonsense. The wiki for Greasemonkey is nearly all reference, not really a "this is a good place to start" kind of article.

Can you recommend a good, updated tutorial for getting started writing userscripts?

I define "good" as:

- How to setup an environment
- Basic skills required to know
- Common use examples
- Best practices

I define "updated" as:

- Written or updated in the last 18 months

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am pretty sure there isn't a tutorial that meets all your requirements. Check out [Jaxov's post / "How To Use Greasemonkey Scripts In Google Chrome?"](https://web.archive.org/web/20210501080114/http://jaxov.com/2009/07/how-to-use-greasemonkey-scripts-in-google-chrome/) for a start.

Anyway, Greasemonkey's not that hard once you know JavaScript; even though Greasemonkey on Chrome can be a bit of a pain.

Play around with it; examine code that works. You could be the one to write the updated "Getting Started" documentation ;)

Also for Chrome, check out [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo).

Answer (score 0):

http://wiki.greasespot.net/Main_Page <-- the page which is opened the first time you install Greasemonkey

Comment: Not very helpful as you probably already know it when getting to the above question, for example I come from here https://wiki.greasespot.net/Avoid_Common_Pitfalls_in_Greasemonkey.